# Find $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda(x - a)^2} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, physics, gaussian-integral

I've tried integrating by parts and using polar coordinates but I couldn't solve it. Heck, I've even tried a simpler [integral of e^(-x² + x) from -∞ to +∞](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20e%5E%28-x%C2%B2%20%2B%20x%29%20from%20-%E2%88%9E%20to%20%2B%E2%88%9E) in the Wolfram Alpha app but it doesn't tell me how it solved it.

Comment: Do you know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x^2} dx = \sqrt{\pi}$? If not, it's called a Gaussian Integral and you should look it up. From there, you just need a substitution.

Comment: Wolfram Alpha gives the result from your URL.

Comment: @Mark I first thought of unwrapping $(x-a)^2$ and stuck with that for no good reason. Thanks for your hint!

Comment: @LKMKlein Yes, but the mobile app usually gives the step by step solution, too. For $e^{-x^2 + x}$ it only showed the result, though, not the derivation.

Comment: @Arch Stanton Yeah, that's actually counterproductive in this case. For example, in your "simplified" version, my first step would be to complete the square in the exponent. Then you're (essentially) back to a Gaussian. Anyway, glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u=\sqrt{\lambda}(x-a)$,

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-\lambda(x - a)^2} dx
=\frac1{\sqrt{\lambda}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} du
= \frac{\sqrt\pi}{\sqrt{\lambda}}$$

where,

$$\left(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-u^2} du\right)^2=\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\infty e^{-r^2}rdrd\theta=\pi$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Substituting $$t=x-a$$ then we have $$dt=dx$$ and our integral is given by $$\int e^{-\lambda t^2}dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(\sqrt{\lambda }
   t\right)}{2 \sqrt{\lambda }}$$